# Receive C++ Byte Stream over UDP in a Java Program

Tags: java, c++, udp

I am having one c++ application that sends a byte buffer (filled from a structure) over UDP.
Another application in Java receives the same buffer and copies data into class (Java Bean class).

I have used below code

```
                byte[] data = packet.getData();
                ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);

                ClickData = (CLICK_ID) is.readObject(); /* CLICK_ID is JAVA CLASS */
```

But when data is received an exception occurs "Invalid Header Stream"

Any solution for same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sending the data from the C++ application in a format the ObjectInputStream would understand?

Comment: Lets rephrase Sami's comment to make it more clear: why do you think that a C++ data structure should resemble the structure of a specific serialized Java object?

Answer (score 1):

If you are exchanging object data between C++ and Java, you need to use a format that they both understand. An object serialized by C++ will not be readable into a Java object because their semantics are different.
One suggestion is to use JSON serialization. C++ app can output JSON which can be read back by Java code. You can use Gson to read it back into an object (bean) if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectInputStream` is for streams that were written by `ObjectOutputStream.`

You should use `DataInputStream` to read the primitives inside the packet.

NB a sequence of structs is not a `byte stream`, and neither is UDP.